# Getting the value of a QLabel with an accessible name using UI Automation

Tags: qt, ui-automation, qlabel

I'm trying to write an UI test (using Windows UI Automation) for an application that uses a QLabel to show an output to a user.

I create the label like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;
    w.setWindowTitle("MyWindowTitle");
    auto centralWidget = new QWidget(&w);
    centralWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    QVBoxLayout layout(centralWidget);

    auto interrestingLabel = new QLabel(centralWidget);
    QString valueCalculatedByApp = "1337";
    interrestingLabel->setText(valueCalculatedByApp);
    //interrestingLabel->setAccessibleName("MyAccessibleName");
    layout.addWidget(interrestingLabel);

    auto uninterrestingLabel = new QLabel(centralWidget);
    uninterrestingLabel->setText("uninterrestingText");
    layout.addWidget(uninterrestingLabel);

    w.setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Inspect.exe now shows the value "1337" as name of the widget:

Without accessible name

[image]

The problem with this would be that my UI test would need to figure out which one is the correct label.

If I uncomment setAccessibleName line, the widget is now identifiable, but I the text is no longer in visible in the properties.

With accessible name

[image]

Is there a way to read the text of a QLabel with an accessible name, or is there another way to make the QLabel identifieable while still being able to read the text?

Comment: Have you looked into this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop

Comment: @hyde Thanks, I tried that, but the object name is not shown inspect.exe, so i don't think I can access it from UIA. (Sorry if my question did not make it clear that I want to use UIA - edited)

Comment: Does that windows test stuff even work with Qt apps? Or have you forced all widgets to be native Windows controls (I mean [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#native-widgets-vs-alien-widgets) )?

Comment: Yes, UIA works for Qt, in general. For example, I can find the location of widgets, press buttons, and read the value of QLineEdits (For them, the value is in LegacyIAccessible.Value and the name is in LegacyIAccessible.Name). I tried adding the line a.setAttribute(Qt::AA_NativeWindows); below the declaration of a, but that did not change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround:

Instead of a QLabel I use a QLineEdit. I set enabled to false so it is not selectable or editable (Like a QLabel) and use QSS to make it look like a QLabel:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSizePolicy>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setAttribute(Qt::AA_NativeWindows);
    QMainWindow w;
    w.setWindowTitle("MyWindowTitle");
    auto centralWidget = new QWidget(&w);
    centralWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    QVBoxLayout layout(centralWidget);

    auto interrestingLabel = new QLineEdit(centralWidget);
    QString valueCalculatedByApp = "1337";
    interrestingLabel->setText(valueCalculatedByApp);
    interrestingLabel->setAccessibleName("MyAccessibleName");
    interrestingLabel->setEnabled(false);
    interrestingLabel->setStyleSheet(
        "border-style: none;"
        "color: black;"
        "background:transparent"
    );
    layout.addWidget(interrestingLabel);

    auto uninterrestingLabel = new QLabel(centralWidget);
    uninterrestingLabel->setText("uninterrestingText");
    layout.addWidget(uninterrestingLabel);

    w.setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```